# Segfault on global constant write

Tags: c++

Consider following code:

```
const int x = 5;     
int main() {
    int* p = const_cast<int*>(&x);
    *p = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/lbcWdT

It causes segmentation fault. Now consider this:

```
int main() {
    const int x = 5;
    int* p = const_cast<int*>(&x);
    *p = 10;
    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/l8rcDq

It works fine.

1. Why Segfault is raised only on global constant write?
2. Why Segfault happened at all?

Comment: it is undefined behaviour in both cases, anything can happen

Comment: Writing a read-only data/code segment, like a global const, generates a segfault.  Writing a value in a stack segment because it's a local const, doesn't generate a segfault.  Either way, it's silly.

Comment: Code with bugs in it will do strange things. Fix the bug and the mystery will go away.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `const`, you are telling the compiler that it's allowed greater freedom of what to do with the object in exchange for your promise you won't ever try to change it. When you break that promise, you enter the land of undefined behaviour.

Sometimes the compiler will respond by creating code in such a way where you could cast away the const, and everything will be fine - as if it was never const in the first place. However, this would be much like "getting lucky" that your code works.

It is never safe to cast away `const` on an object that isn't mutable.

Answer (score 6):

You got undefined behavior in both cases: casting away `const` is only allowed if the object actually, indeed, does refer to a mutable object. You are not allowed to cast away `const` for an object which started its life as a `const` object. These object may live in read-only memory (as is apparently the case in your first example) but that's not required (as is apparently demonstrated by your second example).

Answer (score 0):

the C++ runtime has available two types of memory, read-only and read-write.  Compile-time constants are placed into read-only memory, and cannot be altered even with a cast..  Here the const is a hardware restriction, and writing segfaults.  Automatic variables (function scope variables) are placed on the stack, which is read-write memory.  Here the const is a software restriction, and bypassing the restriction makes writes possible.

The simplest example of read-only vs read-write memory is a string constant:

```
char *p = "string"; p[0] = 'a'; // segfault
char q[] = "string"; q[0] = 'a'; // "atring"
```